# How can I obtain just the results in the output of a SQLCMD job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a job in SQL Studio using powershell:

```
sqlcmd -E -S hostname -b -e -i "User.sql" -o "User.txt"
```

But in the beginning of the output, the select command from the `user.sql` file is echoed and then the results are printed afterwards. Can I have output without the SQL script - just the results?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have the query echoed in your output file you have to call

```
sqlcmd -E -S hostname -b -i "User.sql" -o "User.txt"
```

The documentation of the sqlcmd parameters can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15).

There's also a pure powershell way with `invoke-sqlcmd` cmdlet.

Comment: I would recommend invoke-sqlcmd too.